# How to use AndroidBug5497Workaround

Tags: android

```
public AppStatusBarManager(Activity activity, WebAppInfo info) {
    this.initStatusBarDefaultColor(activity);
    this.mWebAppInfo = info;
    this.mIApp = (IApp)info;
    this.initDirectImmersive();
}
```

Creating the AppStatusBarManager object requires a WebAppInfo. Where can I get a WebAppInfo object